# How to explain centripetal force in terms or relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, centripetal-force, equivalence-principle

At the end of a video of dropping a ball and feathers in a vacuum,  Brian Cox explains that the Ball and Feathers, as understood in terms of General Relativity, aren't falling. (apologies I can only post one link)

There was lots of discussion on a Reddit thread and consensus seemed to be that objects, while travelling in straight lines, warp space time which cause them to move together over time. There was a nice practical demonstration in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlTVIMOix3I).

My question is how does spinning an object counteract the effect of gravity? If I am on the surface of an object[edit: sorry by object here I meant something like a planet!]  and (this is the tough bit) all frames of reference are equally valid, why would it make a difference if the object is spinning or not?

I'll confess to being very confused.

Comment: where did you get that spinning counteracts the effect of gravity?

Comment: @Derek,free-fall and rest on the surface of the source of gravitation are two different situations. In the first, the accelerometer will not show any acceleration, while in the other it will. For a body in rest on the surface, the rotational motion counteracts gravitation to some degree. It's just like when you are on a merry- go-round and you feel a force that is pushing you outside. And now important part - all free-falling frames are "equal". But the frame related to the surface of the Moon is not equal to the frame related to the surface of the Earth.

Comment: For those who haven't see the clip (from BBC's The Human Universe), they do a Galileo style drop in the worlds largest vacuum chamber. It's breathtaking.

Comment: @dmckee no pun intended? ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E43-CfukEgs))

Comment: @user121330 Well, I formed intent *post facto*. I'd smirk more about it if I had thought of it going in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic idea of general relativity is that a freely moving object follows a path through spacetime called a geodesic. By *freely moving* I mean the object experiences no force i.e. if you were that object you would be weightless just as if you were floating in space.

In flat spacetime geodesics are straight lines i.e. a freely moving object moves in a straight line at constant speed. This is just [Newton's first law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_first_law). However general relativity tells us that spacetime is curved due to mass, and in a curved spacetime geodesics are not straight lines. For example the astronauts floating around in the International Space Station are weightless because they are moving along a geodesic. However the mass of the Earth curves the geodesic so it goes in a circle round the Earth.

I'd guess (I haven't seen the video) that this is what Brian Greene is getting at. When we drop the ball and feathers we see them accelerate downwards. However if you were sitting on the ball or amidst the feathers you'd consider yourself to be weightless and not accelerating at all, just like the astronauts in the ISS do.

However if you whirl a stone on a string around your head, or drive a car round a roundabout, or any other form of rotational motion you are not following a geodesic. You know you're not following a geodesic because you can feel a force - the centrifugal force. This force is quite distinct from the gravitational force calculated using general relativity. It does not not have the same origin and it does not have the same effects. For example gravity causes time dilation, e.g. time runs slower near black holes, but the centripetal/centrifugal force does not cause time dilation.

Comment: Nice explanation thanks. 

Just to check my understanding... In my head I'm seeing these 'geodesics' like the lines on a plot of a 2D differential equation. Objects with mass deform those lines and objects will follow the lines unless acted on by an external force. The other way round, from the point of view of the object following the geodesic they aren't experiencing a force.

Am I right in thinking then, that from the point of view of someone on the surface of a spinning planet, the spin is exerting a force at right angles to the geodesic taking them to the centre of the planet?

Comment: @Derek: yes, I think that's a good summary. Re your last sentence, it's the Earth's surface applying a force to your shoes via the friction between them.